# Connectionerror - Elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-admin, amazon-elasticsearch

I am using Amazon elasticsearch service along with postgress. Elasticsearch  works well with every Create, Update operations through django admin. But when I tries to delete from django admin I am getting,

```
ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9371e200f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9371e200f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

I have checked many site but all i got is the syncying command,
`./manage.py search_index --populate -f`
But this is not working. Is there any way which allows me to perform delete through django admin without disabling elasticseach service